# Golang for Android on Windows?

Tags: android, windows, go

I haven't read anything explicitly stating that you can't use Windows but everything that does [walk you through what to do](https://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/README?repo=mobile) seems to involve running a .sh file. Has anybody had any luck compiling any kind of Go for Android, whether it be a library or a full native activity?

Answer (score 1):

No, the all process is tied to Linux (`FROM ubuntu:12.04` in the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/golang/mobile/blob/master/Dockerfile)).

That means you would need to have on Windows a Docker-compliant environment ([like a boot2docker](https://github.com/boot2docker/windows-installer/releases)) in order to launch the

```
docker run -v $GOPATH/src:/src mobile /bin/bash -c 'cd /src/your/project && ./make.bash'
```